# Apigee Emulator: valid API key: but response "InvalidApiKey"

Tags: apigee

Given: Running Apigee Emulator, deployed proxy, Postman with valid API key.

Desired result: proxy in Emulator to return OK 200.

Actual result: response "InvalidApiKey".

Details:

The same API key is being used with Postman to get the OK 200 answers from the Apigee PaaS.
However, an identical request returns the response "InvalidApiKey" from the Apigee Emulator.

Should I provide any appropriate details, please let me know.

Hoping that someone in the community already knows how to resolve or experienced something close.

thank you, Yermek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:
Hope it is going to be helpful for someone with the same question.
The key moment here is that Apigee Emulator (Docker Container) has its own API key.

1. Create a Test bundle in the Emulator inside VS Code.
2. Create API Product there.
3. Create Developer there.
4. Create Developer App there.
5. Export test resources to the Emulator.
6. Find the "consumerKey" under Active test resources, Active developer apps.

useful links:

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Apigee/Apigee-Emulator-valid-API-key-but-response-quot-InvalidApiKey/m-p/163310/highlight/true#M66401

https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/local-development/vscode/tutorial-test